# Is there an integral transform that simplifies functional composition?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Laplace, Fourier and Mellin integral transforms simplify operations like multiplication by a variable, taking derivatives, shifts, dilatations. Are there integral transforms that, in some way, simplify functional composition (by substituting it with a "simpler" operation on images, like multiplication, or summation, or even convolution)? I am aware of existence [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353433/existence-of-integral-transforms-turning-function-composition-into-multiplicat) question, and don't find neither its formulation nor the answer satisfactory.

Comment: What's wrong with the formulation of the question you linked? What don't you like about the solution? If we don't know what your misgivings are, we can't know what kind of answer you'll find "satisfactory"

Comment: It asks specifically about transforms that turn composition into multiplication, and the answer explains why this is (more or less) impossible in the case when the transform is linear and turns composition specifically into multiplication. I don't say the answer or the question is bad, just that it is not what I am asking.